# Positioning with position: sticky

Tags: html, css, sass

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/MrFuze/pen/ExKXxgE) reproducing this issue.

I am working on a personal project, but ran into a weird problem. As you can see blow I have 3 sections, which are supposed to be layed out after each other. Due to the nature of `position: sticky`, I want them to stick to the top after scrolling them. They have however a weird offset and only the third section sticks to the top after scrolling.

```css
//
$enable-sticky-sections: true;

$sticky-section-count: 3;
//

*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont,
    "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans",
    "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  > {
    section {
      position: relative;
    }
  }
}

@if($enable-sticky-sections) {
  body {
    > {
      section {
        position: sticky;
        min-height: 100vh;

        @for $i from 1 through $sticky-section-count - 1 {
          &:nth-of-type(#{$i + 1}) {
            top: calc(#{100 * $i}vh - #{20 * $i}px);
            z-index: #{100 * $i};
            //
            background-color: #{#2196f3 * $i};
            //
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/page.css">
</head>
<body>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create a working snippet reproducing your issue.

Comment: you seems to missunderstand how sticky works. you didn't define any top value for the first section and you are defining very big ones for the two other ... what kind of result are you looking for?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Well, each of the sections has a `min-height` of 100vh. As said, I want them to be layed out vertically after each other, I subtract `20px * $i` to show them a little, at the bottom to suggest for further scrolling, and I use `nth-of-type(#{$i + 1}` to select the second and the third of a total of three sections?

Comment: @TemaniAfif. But maybe I actually do misunderstand `position: sticky`, however yesteday when prototyping it worked out all great.

Comment: *however yesteday when prototyping it worked out all great.* --> show us the prototype because it's still not clear what you want to do .. *to show them a little, at the bottom to suggest for further scrolling* --> not sure what you mean by this but I doubt sticky can do what you want

Comment: @TemaniAfif, does unfortunately no longe exist. Tired me didn't save it

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I figured it out myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that `position: sticky` works like `position: relative` until its scrolled through. Meaning instead of `top: calc(#{100 * $i}vh - #{20 * $i}px);`, I need to go: `margin-top: -#{20 * $i}px;`.

[Here](https://codepen.io/MrFuze/pen/gOrROKa) is a working example

```css
//
$enable-sticky-sections: true;

$sticky-section-count: 3;
//

*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont,
    "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans",
    "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  > {
    section {
      position: relative;
    }
  }
}

@if($enable-sticky-sections) {
  body {
    > {
      section {
        position: sticky;
        min-height: 100vh;

        @for $i from 1 through $sticky-section-count - 1 {
          &:nth-of-type(#{$i + 1}) {
            margin-top: -#{20 * $i}px;
            z-index: #{100 * $i};
            //
            background-color: #{#2196f3 * $i};
            //
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
```

Comment: you don't even need position:sticky in this case, you can remove it

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I know, currently its pure scrolling, but I'll need it in the future.

Comment: My testing of your codepen shows you may also not want to multiply the margin by `$i` as you do here: `margin-top: -#{20 * $i}px;`. The margin shifts by 20px unnecessarily for each iteration. Maybe - maybe not. Just an observation with constructive intent.

Comment: @RobMoll. Hahaha, no worries ;'D. Currently I'm neither using `margin` nor positioning like `top`. I'm going to use the `sections` as `containers` and give them a `padding` that will linearly move to 0 during scrolling.